# Concealing a keyword does not have any effect

Tags: vim

I'm trying to set up a conceal (vim 7.3 only, if `has('conceal') == 1`) for words previously defined as `keywords`, but keywords seem to be immune to conceal. A minimal example in a clean buffer:

```
:set cole=2
:set ft=none
:syntax keyword Function foo baz qux
:syntax match Function "foo" conceal cchar=%
:syntax match Function "bar" conceal cchar=&
```

Now if you type `foo bar` and move to the next line, you should see `foo &`. How can I get it to show `% &`?

If the answer is you can't conceal a keyword, are there alternate ways of defining multiple keywords reliably? In my use case, I have about 5k keywords, but only about 10-20 that I wish to conceal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`conceal` argument can be used for `keyword` as well

replace this line:

```
:syntax match Function "foo" conceal cchar=%
```

with

```
:syntax keyword Function foo conceal cchar=%
```

you could get what you want.

hope it helps

Comment: Welp! Brain fart! Thanks for the answer :)